# Zabbix agent Interrupted system call

Tags: zabbix

Recently, there is a host which indicates me the error message :

```
Get value from agent failed: cannot connect to [] interrupted system call
```

I do not understand what happens to it, this host uses an agent zabbix on the port 10050.
Except that on my 10 other hosts which are also with a zabbix agent there is no problem, it's really only on one that I have this problem.
I've tried to search on the web but nothing works.

Could it be a problem with the agent installed on the host?